# Remove duplicate texts in one cell

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am currently shaping my data. I have one column called "Centro". However, there are so many duplicate texts in just one cell. How Can I remove the duplicate texts and only show distinct texts? Anyone can help on this?Thanks!!

[image: Issues]

This is my code:

```
let
    Source = Etapa_2_Caricam,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Material"}, {{"mynewtable", each _, type table [Material=number, Num Form=text, Created on=date, FechaCreac=date, Initiator=text, Texto tarea=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "NoForm", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Num Form")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"NoForm", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Iniciador", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Initiator")),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Iniciador", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values1", {{"Iniciador", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ", "), type text}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter", "FechaInicio", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Created on")),
    #"Extracted Values2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom2", {"FechaInicio", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values2", {{"FechaInicio", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ", "), type text}}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1", "FechaFinalTarea", each let dates = Table.Column([mynewtable],"FechaCreac") in [min = List.Min(dates), max = List.Max(dates)]),
  expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom3", "FechaFinalTarea", {"min", "max"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(expanded,{{"min", type date}, {"max", type date}, {"FechaInicio", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TextoTarea", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Texto tarea")),
    #"Extracted Values3" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom4", {"TextoTarea", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Values3",{{"Material", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1", {{"FechaInicio", type text}}, "en-US"), "FechaInicio", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"FechaInicio.1", "FechaInicio.2", "FechaInicio.3"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"FechaInicio.1", Int64.Type}, {"FechaInicio.2", Int64.Type}, {"FechaInicio.3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"FechaInicio.2", "FID"}, {"FechaInicio.1", "FIM"}, {"FechaInicio.3", "FIA"}}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"FIM", type text}, {"FID", type text}, {"FIA", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type3", "FechaInicio", each [FID]&"/"&[FIM]&"/"&[FIA]),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom5",{{"FechaInicio", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type4",{"FIM", "FID", "FIA"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Material", "mynewtable", "NoForm", "Iniciador", "FechaInicio", "min", "max", "TextoTarea"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns", {{"max", type text}}, "en-US"), "max", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"max.1", "max.2", "max.3"}),
    #"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"max.1", type text}, {"max.2", type text}, {"max.3", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type5", "FechaFinal", each [max.2]&"/"&[max.1]&"/"&[max.3]),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom6",{"Material", "mynewtable", "NoForm", "Iniciador", "FechaInicio", "FechaFinal", "min", "max.1", "max.2", "max.3", "TextoTarea"}),
    #"Changed Type6" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns1",{{"FechaFinal", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type6",{"max.1", "max.2", "max.3"}),
    #"Changed Type7" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2",{{"FechaFinal", type text}, {"FechaInicio", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type7", "Table", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"NoMatAnt")),
    #"Extracted Values4" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom7", {"Table", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values4", "Text Before Delimiter", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Table], ", "), type text),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter",{"Text Before Delimiter"}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns3", {{"Table", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ", "), type text}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter2", "Table", "Table - Copy"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Duplicated Column","CR","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Table - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","DO","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Table - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","GT","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Table - Copy"}),
    #"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2","PR","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Table - Copy"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Replaced Value3",{{"Table - Copy", "No.FormAnt"}, {"Table", "No.MatAnt"}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{{"TextoTarea", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Added Custom8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Centro", each Table.Column([mynewtable],"Ce")),
    #"Extracted Values5" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom8", {"Centro", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to split the comma separated values (Centro field), into different rows and then remove duplicates. Then you can group them up again to get the comma separated values. For the purpose of demonstrating, I created a table with two fields: PrimaryKey and Centro. Then I used the following steps to get to the desired output:

Source Information:

```
= Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUUrUSdJJUorViVYyAvKSdVJ0knWSlWJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), 
let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [PrimaryKey = _t, Centro = _t])
```

Split Column By delimiter (You can do this by selecting the "Split Column - By Delimiter" option in the Transform tab, you have to choose the Centro field before selecting this option):

```
= Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Centro", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",")}}), "Centro")
```

Remove Duplicates (You can do this by choosing "Remove Rows - Remove Duplicates" from the Home tab, make sure you choose all the columns before selecting this option):

```
= Table.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter")
```

Grouped Rows (You can do this by choosing the "Group By" option in the transform tab, but you would have to edit the query a little to use the delimiter aggregation):

```
= Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"PrimaryKey"}, {{"Centro_New", each Text.Combine([Centro],","), type text}})
```

This should give you the desired output. Hope this helps.

Edit: You can combine all these into a single step and use the following formula:

```
= Table.Group(Table.Distinct(Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Centro", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",")}}), "Centro")),{"PrimaryKey"}, {{"Centro_New", each Text.Combine([Centro],","), type text}})
```

Comment: Hi, I have found an example, however, When I applied the code my old table got expanded. code: RemovedDuplicates = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Keywords Used In Last Week", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Transform(Text.Split(_,","), Text.Trim)),", ")}})
in
    RemovedDuplicates

Comment: I shared it in individual steps, because it would be easier to debug. I have added a combined calculation at the end of my answer if you prefer that. I am not sure about the way some of the functions are used in the example attached in your comment.

Comment: Hi Ben, if this answered your question, make sure you mark it as the answer. This will make it easier for someone who is looking for an answer to the same question in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers